# Why the imageview remain the same when I change locale in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, locale

Here is the code for changing language

```
eng.setOnClickListener(setChangeLangListener("en"));
chi.setOnClickListener(setChangeLangListener("zh"));


public OnClickListener setChangeLangListener(final String lang) {
        OnClickListener changeLangListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Configuration config = new Configuration(getResources()
                        .getConfiguration());

                if (lang.equals("en")) {
                    config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                    chi.setTextColor(oldColor);
                    eng.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                            android.R.color.white));
                } else {
                    config.locale = Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE;
                    eng.setTextColor(oldColor);
                    chi.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                            android.R.color.white));
                }

                getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                        getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
        };
        return changeLangListener;
    }
```

The problem is , when I change the locale the image view does not refresh to reflect the changes , I am using tabhost and the change language button is inside the fragment, so I have to change the actvitiy + inside fragment . How to fix it ? thanks.

The tabhost

```
tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec("Home").setIndicator("",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_about)), Home.class,
                null);
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec("About").setIndicator("",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_about)), About.class,
                null);
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec("Check").setIndicator("",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_check)), Selfie.class,
                null);
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec("Gallery").setIndicator("",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_gallery)),
                PhotoGallery.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec("LeaderBoard").setIndicator("",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_board)),
                LeaderBoard.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec("Events").setIndicator("",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_events)), Events.class,
                null);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
        setTabBg(tabHost);
```

The fragment

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        loginBtn = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_connectFB);
        eng = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_eng);
        chi = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_chi);
```

Comment: You need to reload the activity

Comment: would you mind further explain it? I would not perfer using finish() since I am using google analytic so it may double count the entry rate

Comment: The other option that comes to mind is to reload the image manually. I'm not in my computer, so can't give a proper answer

Comment: What should the ImageView do when the locale is changed?

Answer (score 0):

your `View.OnClickListener` is wrong. Or at least the way I read it. You want to change things when you press either on eng or chi. Imo you should inline it, as member class for instance, or let your activity implements OnClickListenerm, and set the same for both the TextView. For instance:

```
 OnClickListener changeLangListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Configuration config = new Configuration(getResources()
                    .getConfiguration());

            if (arg0.getId() = R.id.btn_eng) {
                config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                chi.setTextColor(oldColor);
                eng.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                        android.R.color.white));
            } else if (arg0.getId() = R.id.btn_chi) {
                config.locale = Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE;
                eng.setTextColor(oldColor);
                chi.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                        android.R.color.white));
            }

            getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    };

eng.setOnClickListener(changeLangListener);
chi.setOnClickListener(changeLangListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The listener actually change that two text view, the problem is other views does not change accordingly. Would you mind provide some suggestion of how to change the views manually? thanks

Answer (score 0):

public void setLocale(String lang) {

```
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

    onConfigurationChanged(conf);
}



@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.keyboard));
    greet.setText(R.string.greet);
    textView1.setText(R.string.langselection);

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}
```